# Swift: Protocol That Accepts Subclasses

Tags: swift, protocols

I have a protocol:

```
protocol InspectableSource
{
    var headerView: NSView? { get }
    var footerView: NSView? { get }
    var mainContentViews: [NSView] { get }
}
```

Then I have a class that adopts this protocol:

```
class MyClass: InspectableSource
{
    var mainContentViews: [MyNSViewSubclass]
}
```

The instance of `MyClass` provides `mainContentViews`, which is full of objects that are subclasses of `NSView`. Swift whines about this and won't compile...because it's Swift.

So how do I declare in my protocol that `mainContentViews` can be ANY type of object that is an `NSView` or a subclass thereof?

Comment: Hi @MartinR. Your assessment is not correct. That other question is about protocol inheritance and the answer to it is full of gobbledygook that only a language expert could parse. It is of no help to those transitioning to or learning Swift for the first time. Sweeper and RickyMo were actually helpful. You were not.

Comment: I took my time to find a Q&A which contains an excellent explanation of the problem. And if you read until “Another workaround is just to define a dummy property in order to satisfy the protocol requirement” then you'll find exactly the solution proposed below.

Comment: @MartinR What you're not hearing is that I spent an hour searching dozens of phrases to try to turn up a discussion of this issue and never came across that post. Because it's not phrased in a way that folks who aren't...you...would think to use or google. That, and the impenetrable meta-discussion about Swift as a work-in-progress that leads the answer section make it less useful to mere mortals. Sweeper helped me and his answer will help others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use associated types:

```
protocol InspectableSource
{
    associatedtype ViewType : NSView
    var headerView: ViewType? { get }
    var footerView: ViewType? { get }
    var mainContentViews: [ViewType] { get }
}
```

And in your conforming class:

```
class MyClass: InspectableSource
{
    typealias ViewType = MyNSViewSubclass
    var mainContentViews: [MyNSViewSubclass]
    // ...
}
```

But note that this will prevent you from using `InspectableSource` as the type of a variable.

If you really want to have `InspectableSource` as the type of a variable. You can try this less type safe approach:

```
class MyClass: InspectableSource {
    Var mainContentViews: [MyNSViewSubclass]
    var inspectableMainContentViews: [NSView] {
        return mainContentViews 
    }
}

protocol InspectableSource {
    var inspectableMainContentView: [NSView] { get }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sweeper. I did get pretty far down the 'associatedType' rabbit hole, but that places too many limits on the protocol, as you point out.

Comment: My issue is that I have several variants of 'MyClass' that all want to have a different kind of NSView subclass in the 'mainContentViews', and I **want** to enforce that. (Each variant of 'MyClass' should accept only one type of NSView-subclass). So leaving it as just 'NSView' prevents the compiler from type-checking that.

Comment: @Bryan what about naming the protocol properties with a prefix, like `inspectable` and then you can have two declarations of the same property, one called `inspectableMainContentViews` of type `[NSView]` and `mainContentViews` of type `[MyNSViewSubclass]`?

Comment: Thanks! You beat me to it. Adding another read-only property to 'MyClass' that just casts the "real" property as [NSView] is exactly what I ended up doing. It's kludgy, but it works.

Comment: @MartinR yes it seems to be the same idea. The only difference is that the linked question is about a protocol member having a protocol type whereas this question is about a protocol member having a class type. I am not sure whether that constitutes a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

If you can modify `MyClass`, I suggest using a dedicated field to store your `[MyNSViewSubclass]`, then conforms to `InspectableSource` via computed property.

```
protocol InspectableSource
{
    var mainContentViews: [NSView] { get }
}

class MyClass: InspectableSource
{
    var mainContentViews : [NSView]{
        return myNSViews
    }
    var myNSViews : [MyNSViewSubclass]

    init() {
        self.myNSViews = []
    }
}
```